Is it possible to get 100% Dodge chance?
I remember seeing multiple upgrades to Dodge Chance, in one Arcanum along with multiple Boons, but I forget exactly what possibilities made 100% Dodge seem achievable.
Is it achievable? Is there a hidden cooldown between dodges to make Melinoe not invincible?

As per the wiki:

Dodge chance is additive (stacking), meaning it's possible to reach 100% dodge and be nigh invincible.

It's indeed possible to achieve above 100% dodge with the right boons, but it will always require Evade Evade Evade which loses 2% dodge for every attack successfully dodged.
The maximum dodge achievable without Evade Evade Evade (or after dodging 25 attacks with it) is:
15% (Wispy Wiles (Aphrodites)) + 15% (Word of Smaller Stature (Circe)) + 25% (max level Greater Evasion (Hermes)) + 7% (Hot Pot (Hestia), doubled to 14% if enemy is scorched) + 12% (V-The Messenger arcana card) = 74% or 81% against scorched
Adding Evade Evade Evade's 50%, you will have above 100% dodge for 12 (against non-scorched) attacks, which you will be guaranteed to dodge, after which you will be at exactly 100% and lose 2% for each attack dodged until you're back at 74%/81%.
You may also get a conditional 1% with Selene's Tension.

Is Hestia's Hot Pot new? "Innate Dodge Chance: +4%/+5%/+6%/+7%" but needs a Scorch applier Boon first? https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Hestia/Boons

@Malady you're right, the max is in fact at least 74% (or 81% against scorched enemies). it seems the wiki doesn't list it on the dodge page.

I wonder if all the Boons can't be leveled by Pom of Power. IIRC Greater Evasion can only be boosted by its Rarity, but not sure where I heard that.
